# Query: Select all where date of first (ordered by date) child object is in date range

Tags: php, mysql, date, parent-child, date-range

I have a parent object, let's say an Event.

This event can occur on several dates, so we have EventDates.

Now I want to have all Events where the Event's start date is inside a date range (for example a school year).

Normally that would be easy, but since the start date is not a direct property of the Event, we need to join on the EventDates.

I already tried the following (unorthodox) method, which seemed to have worked a while, but suddenly doesn't anymore:

```
SELECT *, min(ed_date) AS ed_date FROM events
LEFT JOIN event_dates ON events.e_id = event_dates.ed_event_id
WHERE ed_date >= '2016-09-01'
AND ed_date <= '2017-08-31'
```

Apparently, when there's an EventDate within the range above, it will take the first one in that range as the "min(ed_date)" instead of the actual minimum date.

If there's already a solution posted to this, I must've missed it.
Any help is appreciated. I'd hate to have to use php to find all the separate dates and use those ID's to apply an IN array filter with those results.

Separately saving the start date in the event itself may also be an option, but I don't like redundant data.

If you have a question, or something's unclear, be sure to ask.

Update.
There was a question for some sample data, hope I'm doing this right:

```
table events:
e_id:int(11) e_category_id:int(11) e_title:varchar(255) e_status:int(11)

table event_dates:
ed_id:int(11) ed_event_id:int(11) ed_title:varchar(255) ed_date:date
```

Let's say there are 2 events: E1 & E2. (titles, categories & statuses aren't really relevant for this case)
3 event_dates are linked to each of these events.
Dates for E1: 03/05/2017 - 05/05/2017 - 08/05/2017
Dates for E2: 28/04/2017 - 02/05/2017 - 04/05/2017

Now I want all events of which the start date of that event (respectively 03/05/2017 & 28/04/2017) is within the date range 01/05/2017-31/05/2017.

If I do the following:

```
SELECT *, min(ed_date) as ed_date FROM events
LEFT JOIN event_dates ON event_dates.ed_event_id = events.e_id
WHERE ed_date >= '2017-05-01'
AND ed_date <= '2017-05-31'
GROUP BY events.e_id
```

(The GROUP BY wasn't included in the first select above, apologies.)

Then I get both events, the ed_date of the second event being 02/05/2017.

It got the min(ed_date) of the dates that were in the range (03/05/2017 & 02/05/2017), instead of the actual min(ed_date) (03/05/2017 & 28/04/2017).

Is it clear like this?

Comment: You want to get the first date from the event_dates and not the date from the events table? And events can have multiple records in event_dates? If so you need to issue the Min function to the date field of event_dates and use a group by in id field. Would be nice if you can provide a sample data.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Also, it's good practice to qualify your table names, so that we (and you) can easily see which tables the columns come from.